# Show compiler command line of CMake with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I am using open folder functionality of VS2019, and I would like to see flags being used to compile my code.

Compilation database does not seem to be generated with my generator(Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64) when I do CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS , also `set(VERBOSE ON)` does not work.

Comment: Do `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)` in CMakeLists.txt to generate a compile_commands.json file.

Comment: @Jasper Juhl like I said it does not work for MSVC generator.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

You must use $ENV{} syntax to check/access environment variables such as CMAKE_* within `CMakeLists.txt`. See my https://stackoverflow.com/a/68724763/717355

Answer (score 1):

`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` option is ignored in VS generator:

> This option is implemented only by Makefile Generators and the Ninja. It is ignored on other generators.

See full doc: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html