# Are all CMAKE_ variables automatically defined in CMake (esp CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS)

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, undefined

In one of our `CMakeLists.txt` files we have a test to decide if the `compile_commands.json` should be exported.

```
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS)
    set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS TRUE)
```

The `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` variable was new in V3.5, so before then, this test should trigger (it's inside a wider test for the OS in use), but really I am wanting it to trigger if it hasn't been set on a command line (i.e. an auto generation via Visual Studio (Ninja) detecting the presence of the `CMakeLists.txt` file). It doesn't appear to be working like that.

It this (`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` variable), and the other `CMAKE_` variable always implicitly *defined* when CMake runs?

I'm aware of the 'two runs' problem for `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`, which is separate to the `if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_*)` question.

Comment: You cannot determine whether a variable was set on the command line specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short:
You must use `$ENV{}` syntax to check/access environment variables such as `CMAKE_*`.  It is not easy to find that detail in the manual as the pages lack obvious back links to the relevant info.
[end TL;DR]

In [ENV Operator man page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/ENV.html) it states "To test whether an environment variable is defined, use the signature `if(DEFINED ENV{<name>})` of the `if()` command."

The `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` is listed as an [environment variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-env-variables.7.html#manual:cmake-env-variables(7)). Also that "Environment variables have global scope in a CMake process. They are never cached.". The [set command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-environment-variable) also requires that syntax. (some answers [elsewhere](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16588) attempt to cache it because they also failed to set it correctly).

My working test code:

```
if(NOT DEFINED ENV{CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS})
    message("ENV(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS) NOT DEFINED")
    set($ENV{CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS} TRUE)
endif()
```

All in all, a tricky to resolve mistake.

Comment: It is [**also listed as a normal CMake variable**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) and the environment variable is used to initialize the normal variable on the first run.

Comment: That's also not the right syntax for setting an environment variable and even if you set it correctly, it won't cause `compile_commands.json` to be created

Comment: @AlexReinking It is now working for me, when it wasn't before. The CMakeLists.txt is run automatically by the Visual Studio Ninja generator when using the Open Folder method - this then needs to see if it (export flag) has yet been defined (no), and then set the value (there is other logic), so that the compile_commands.json is exported as the project is generated.

Comment: I promise you that if it's working, it's not because of the code in your answer. The syntax is wrong! It should be `set(ENV{...} ...)` without the `$`. Not that correcting this mistake would do anything _anyway_, unless this code is before the first call to `project()`, which it shouldn't be. CMake uses the value of the non-env variable to decide whether to produce `compile_commands.json` and uses the env-var to initialize a cache entry inside `project()`.

Answer (score 0):

> It this (`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` variable), and the other CMAKE_ variable always implicitly defined when CMake runs?

The answer to this part of the question is "it depends on which variable you're talking about". For the specific case of `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`, it works as follows:

1. When the `CMakeLists.txt` is first configured, at the start of execution, `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` is not defined.
2. When project is called, the cache variable `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` is created and **initialized** with the value of `ENV{CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS}`.
3. Subsequent re-configures will load the value of `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` from the cache and not consult the environment variable.
4. In any case, CMake decides whether or not to generate `compile_commands.json` based on the value of the *normal* variable `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`; if it does not exist, then it looks at the cache variable. If even this does not exist (i.e. if you manually `unset()` it), then it will *not* generate `compile_commands.json`. It **absolutely does not** consult the environment variable at this point.

Remember also that setting an environment variable affects on the current CMake process. It does not escape into the controlling terminal, nor will it survive until a custom command executes. Note that `execute_process` *will* see the variable, and there is a related [bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22043) in CTest's build-and-test mode that is too painful to describe here.

Loading a toolchain file that sets the cache variable, or setting it in a parent project (i.e. `add_subdirectory`) *cannot be distinguished* from setting it at the command line. **There is simply no way to reliably detect this case.**

---

If you want `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` to be `ON` by default, then you may add this code before the call to `project()` (which I do not normally recommend doing):

```
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS AND
   NOT DEFINED ENV{CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS} AND
   CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Ninja|Unix Makefiles")
  set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS "ON"
      CACHE BOOL "Enable/Disable output of compile commands during generation.")
  mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS)
endif()
```